Approach for installing node_modules while dockerizing the node js application

Dockerfile 1:
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY ..
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "index.js"]


Dockerfile 2:
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
COPY ..
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "index.js"]



How are these two Dockerfiles different? When I build the docker file, everything will be executed except CMD step, but how are they different?

You first need to do COPY .. and then npm install, because otherwise package.json is not present and npm will not know what to install (so DOCKERFILE-2 is actually incorrect)

What you should actually do is neither of those. Use layer caching: copy in the package and lock files; then install (with ci, not just install); then copy everything else in.

On the Dockerfile 2 you set a WORKDIR and, with nothing there, the next step is RUN npm install, which executes in this empty directory.
Taking a guess here, but I believe you are confused because your project is inside a /app folder itself. But remember the core idea of a container is to be isolated. The container has its own filesystem, whichever name you pick for WORKDIR does not have to match anything.

the difference is in the Dockerfile 1  you are copying the directory before the packages installation
the Dockerfile 2 one you're copying after copying the directory
the first might not be working because package.json not exist in the working directory
